# Use $size on all documents in array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here's the structure part of my collection:

```
_id: ObjectId("W"),
names: [
    {
        number: 1,
        list: ["A","B","C"]
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        list: ["B"]
    },
    {
        number: 3,
        list: ["A","C"]
    }
    ...
],
...
```

I use this request:

```
db.publication.aggregate( [ { $match: { _id: ObjectId("54a1de90453d224e80f5fc60") } }, { $group: { _id: "$_id", SizeName: { $first: { $size: { $ifNull: [ "$names", [] ] } } }, names: { $first: "$names" } } } ] );
```

but I would now use *$size* in every documents of my **names** array.

Is it possible to get this result (where "**sizeList**" is the result of *$size*) :

```
_id: ObjectId("W"),
SizeName: 3,
names: [
    {
        SizeList: 3,
        number: 1,
        list: ["A","B","C"]
    },
    {
        SizeList: 1,
        number: 2,
        list: ["B"]
    },
    {
        SizeList: 2,
        number: 3,
        list: ["A","C"]
    }
    ...
],
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you really want here is a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage and use [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to alter the contents of the array members:

```js
db.names.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "SizeName": { "$size": "$names" },
        "names": { "$map": {
            "input": "$names",
            "as": "el",
            "in": {
                "SizeList": { "$size": "$$el.list" },
                "number": "$$el.number",
                "list": "$$el.list"
            }
        }}
    }}
])
```

You can alternately process with **`$unwind`** and group it all back again, but that's kind of long winded when you have MongoDB 2.6 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the most efficient way, but I think it does what you're aiming to do:

```
db.publication.aggregate( [ 
    { $unwind: '$names' },
    { $unwind: '$names.list' },
    { $group: {
        _id: { _id: "$_id", number: "$names.number" },
        SizeList: { $sum: 1 },
        list: { $push: "$names.list" }
      }
    },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        names: {
            $push: {
                number: "$_id.number",
                list: "$list",
                SizeList: "$SizeList"
            }
        },
        SizeName: {$sum: 1}
      }
    }
]);
```

Comment: You might not have been aware that the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator referred to by the OP in their question is a MongoDB 2.6 and greater feature that efficiently reports the size of an array. So it is no longer necessary to unwind arrays just to count the elements.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is awesome, Neil - Thanks